# Radio buttons get unselected while scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have two radio buttons on UITableView Cell.I am able to select one of them while scrolling UITableView down but when I scroll tableview up all radio buttons get unselected. After scrolling also I want to keep them selected but I am not able to do that....So please anyone having solution help me. Thank you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    leftBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    leftBtnclick.tag=999;
    [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    if (screenHeight == 667)
    {
        [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 59, 30, 30)];
     }
    else if(screenHeight == 480)
    {
        [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 30, 30)];

    }

    [leftBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(leftTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.leftOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:leftBtnclick];

    rightBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightBtnclick.tag=1000;
    [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    if (screenHeight == 667)
    {
       [rightBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 59, 30, 30)];
    }
    else if(screenHeight == 480)
    {
        [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 30, 30)];

    }

    [rightBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 59, 30, 30)];
    [rightBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(rightTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.rightOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(rightTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rightBtnclick];

    cell.numberLbl.text = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.questionLbl.text = [questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.leftOptBtn setTitle:[leftOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.rightOptBtn setTitle:[rightOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}

-(void)leftTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    leftTickBtn.selected=!leftTickBtn.selected;
    for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
    {
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==1000)
        {
            UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

            if(leftTickBtn.selected)
            {
                rightTickBtn.selected=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                rightTickBtn.selected=YES;
            }

        }
    }

}

-(void)rightTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    rightTickBtn.selected=!rightTickBtn.selected;


    for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
    {
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==999)
        {
            UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

            if(rightTickBtn.selected)
            {
                leftTickBtn.selected=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                leftTickBtn.selected=YES;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This problem rises sometime by reusing tableviewcell. Remove `if` statement and write these line `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];`  out of `if`, and try again.

Comment: Still not working......@SweetAngel

Comment: How many rows are there in your tableview?

Comment: 16 rows ...@SweetAngel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my question. UITableView cells are reusable when you scroll tableview cell gets reused that's why radio button selection disappears. So solution is store your selection in one array use that array in cellForRowAtIndexPath. See code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    leftBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    leftBtnclick.tag=999;
    cell.leftOptBtn.tag=999;
    [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 59, 30, 30)];
    [leftBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(leftTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.leftOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:leftBtnclick];


    rightBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightBtnclick.tag=1000;
    cell.rightTickBtn.tag=1000;
    [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [rightBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(190, 59, 30, 30)];


    [rightBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(rightTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.rightOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(rightBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:rightBtnclick];

    cell.numberLbl.text = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.questionLbl.text = [questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.leftOptBtn setTitle:[leftOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.rightOptBtn setTitle:[rightOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if ([[answerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        leftBtnclick.selected=YES;
        rightBtnclick.selected=NO;

    }
    else if ([[answerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        leftBtnclick.selected=NO;
        rightBtnclick.selected=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBtnclick.selected=NO;
        rightBtnclick.selected=NO;
    }
    return cell;
}



-(void)leftTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:questionTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [questionTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    [answerArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath1.row withObject:@"YES"];

    UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    leftTickBtn.selected=!leftTickBtn.selected;
    for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
    {
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==1000)
        {
            UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

            if(leftTickBtn.selected)
            {
                 rightTickBtn.selected=NO;

            }
            else
            {
                rightTickBtn.selected=YES;

            }


        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Answer Array: %@",answerArray);
}

-(void)rightTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:questionTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [questionTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    [answerArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath1.row withObject:@"NO"];

    UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    rightTickBtn.selected=!rightTickBtn.selected;


    for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
    {
        if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==999)
        {
            UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

            if(rightTickBtn.selected)
            {
                leftTickBtn.selected=NO;

            }
            else
            {
                leftTickBtn.selected=YES;

            }

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Answer Array: %@",answerArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created only one `leftTickBtn` and `rightTickBtn` and updated it each time when row is created. So finally whatever you have done with radio button, its affected to only last button.

Update your code as below :

```
UIButton *leftBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
leftBtnclick.tag=999+indexPath.row;

UIButton *rightBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightBtnclick.tag=1000+indexPath.row;
```

And implement methods like :

```
- (IBAction)leftTickBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = TRUE;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tblAppointment cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1000-sender.tag inSection:0]];

    for (id view in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            // your code
             UIButton *btnRight = (UIButton *)view;
             if (sender.selected == TRUE)
                 btnRight.selected = FALSE;
             else
                 btnRight.selected = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
- (IBAction)rightTickBtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = TRUE;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tblAppointment cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:999-sender.tag inSection:0]];

    for (id view in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            // your code
             UIButton *btnLeft = (UIButton *)view;
             if (sender.selected == TRUE)
                 btnLeft.selected = FALSE;
             else
                 btnLeft.selected = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but it is not working for me...getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because of how the reusable cell works.
When you scroll away from the cell you made changes on the radio button , and then try to scroll back to that specific row ,a reusable cell `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` does not guarantee that it will dequeue the exact same cell you made the changes and most likely it will dequeue a cell that you have not made any changes

You will need to keep track of the buttons selections in a List outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and reassign the selections to your radio buttons in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` much like the same idea with assigning the cell text every time with `cell.numberLbl.text = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` by using the indexPath.row in an array

See modification [1] , [2] and [3] on the code below (haven't tested it but you get the idea)

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
        customCell *cell = (customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        leftBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        leftBtnclick.tag=999;
        [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [leftBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        if (screenHeight == 667)
        {
            [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 59, 30, 30)];
         }
        else if(screenHeight == 480)
        {
            [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 30, 30)];

        }

        [leftBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(leftTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.leftOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:leftBtnclick];

        rightBtnclick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        rightBtnclick.tag=1000;
        [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightBtnclick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        if (screenHeight == 667)
        {
           [rightBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 59, 30, 30)];
        }
        else if(screenHeight == 480)
        {
            [leftBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 30, 30)];

        }

        [rightBtnclick setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 59, 30, 30)];
        [rightBtnclick addTarget:self action:@selector(rightTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.rightOptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(rightTickBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:rightBtnclick];

        cell.numberLbl.text = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.questionLbl.text = [questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.leftOptBtn setTitle:[leftOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.rightOptBtn setTitle:[rightOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            //[1]Set values for left and right 
    rightTickBtn.selected = [RightTicksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    leftTickBtn.selected = [LeftTicksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)leftTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
        leftTickBtn.selected=!leftTickBtn.selected;
        for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
        {
            if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==1000)
            {
                UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

                if(leftTickBtn.selected)
                {
                    rightTickBtn.selected=NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    rightTickBtn.selected=YES;
                }
//[2]Update RightTickArray At Pos
     [RightTickArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] = leftTickBtn.selected;
        }
    }

    }

    -(void)rightTickBtnClicked:(id)sender
    {

        UIButton *rightTickBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
        rightTickBtn.selected=!rightTickBtn.selected;


        for(UIView *vw in [[sender superview]subviews])
        {
            if([vw isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && vw.tag==999)
            {
                UIButton *leftTickBtn=(UIButton *)vw;

                if(rightTickBtn.selected)
                {
                    leftTickBtn.selected=NO;
                }
                else
                {
                    leftTickBtn.selected=YES;
                }

    //[3]Update LeftTickArray At Pos
        [LeftTicksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] = leftTickBtn.selected;
                }
            }


    }
```

Comment: your idea is right but your code is not working for me. Modification 2) and 3) giving error

Comment: @alex sorry i didn't have a mac that time to properly test it , upvote if it helped you